# Finding $(\frac{f}{g})(x)$ when $f$ and $g$ functions are given.

Tags: functions

Function $f$ and $g$ are defined by

$ f(x)=x^2 -2x+1 \space$  and $\space g(x) = (x-1)(x+3), \space$ find $\space (\frac{f}{g})(x)$ and its domain.

How do I find $(\frac{f}{g})(x)$ with the two given functions?

Comment: Well... You calculate it?

Comment: I'm guessing you don't understand the meaning of $(f/g)(x)$. It means $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. Can you proceed now?

Comment: After performing the division i get $1+4−4x/x2+2x−3$ am i doing it right?

Answer (score 1):

Well, $f/g$ is
$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{(x-1)^2}{(x-1)(x+3)}=\frac{x-1}{x+3}$$
which is needed $x+3\neq 0$.

Its graph is just https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-1%29%2F%28x%2B3%29

Comment: I'd say the domain of the quotient is $\mathbb R\backslash\{1,-3\}$. That $x=1$ is a 'removable discontinuity' is true, but formally the quotient isn't defined at $x=1$.